# Por que esquemas normalizados até 3FN não possuem relacionamentos N:N?

Tags: banco-de-dados, modelagem, arquitetura-de-software, tabela-banco-de-dados, normalização

## Explicação do conceito

Entendo que por definição um esquema de banco de dados encontra-se na **3FN**, quando está na 1FN,2FN e **não** possui dependência transitiva.

**Dependência transitiva** é quando um atributo **NÃO chave**, além de depender de um atributo **chave** também depende de um atributo **NÃO** chave.

Exemplo: [image: imagem]

No exemplo do livro, o atributo `Cpf_gerente` é um atributo não-chave que depende do atributo `Dnumero` (não-chave) e do atributo `CPF` (chave).

> Legenda
>
> X: Atributo chave `CPF`.
>
> Y: Atributo NÃO-chave `Dnumero`.
>
> Z: Atributo NÃO-chave `CPF_Gerente`.

Então pela notação temos o conceito de transitividade explicado dessa forma

> `X -> Y e Y -> Z e X -> Z`.

Traduzindo seria assim:

> `CPF` determina exclusivamente `Dnumero` ou `Dnumero` depende funcionalmente de `CPF`.
>
> `Dnumero` determina de forma exclusiva `CPF_GERENTE` ou `CPF_GERENTE` depende funcionalmente de `Dnumero`.

Após encontrar todas as DF(**D**ependências **F**uncionais), veja que a tabela FUNC_DEP é dividida em duas e passa a eliminar a antiga dependência transitiva.

Logo temos o esquema dentro da forma normal 3FN.

## Tá, mas qual é a dúvida?

Mesmo sabendo o conceito acima não consegui entender porque é correto afirma que *em modelo relacional normalizado até a 3FN é correto afirma que a 3FN contém apenas relacionamentos 1:1 e 1:N.*

Para quem tiver interesse de ver a questão, ela encontra-se [**aqui**](https://www.estudegratis.com.br/questao-de-concurso/144572):

> Considere que um modelo relacional normalizado até a
>
> I. 3FN contém apenas relacionamentos N:M.
>
> II. 3FN contém apenas relacionamentos 1:1 e 1:N.
>
> III. 3FN não pode conter dependências funcionais entre atributos não-chave.
>
> IV. 1FN ou 2FN não pode conter dependências funcionais entre atributos não-chave e nem relacionamentos N:M.
>
> Está correto o que se afirma APENAS em
>
> **A.** II, III e IV.
>
> **B.** II e III.
>
> **C.** I e III.
>
> **D.** II.
>
> **E.** I.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vamos supor que queremos relacionar quais cachorros têm quais donos e vice-versa. Temos que uma mesma pessoa pode ser dona de vários cachorros e um cachorro pode ter mais de um dono. Também existem cachorros sem donos e pessoas que não têm cachorros.

Poderíamos implementar na tabela de pessoas, um campo com os ids de todos os cachorros que ela possui e na tabela de cachorros um campo com os ids de todos os seus donos. Isso é possível, mas é uma violação da 1FN.

Assim sendo, para chegar-se a 1FN, deve-se eliminar-se os campos multivalorados. Teremos que criar uma tabela que diz quais são os cachorros de cada pessoa e uma que diz quais são os donos de cada cachorro. Ocorre que essas tabelas são na verdade uma só. Assim sendo, usamos uma tabela intermediária, onde um relacionamento **M:N** entre as tabelas **A** e **B** é implementado por meio de uma tabela nova **C** onde temos relacionamentos **1:M** entre **A** e **C** e **1:N** entre **B** e **C**. Ou seja, o relacionamento **M:N** foi quebrado em dois relacionamentos, um **1:M** e um **1:N**. Na tabela **C**, não há nenhum campo além das duas chaves estrangeiras e ambos são parte da chave primária.

Logo, se os relacionamentos **M:N** devem ser decompostos (e portanto eliminados) para atingir-se a 1FN, então não há como eles persistirem ao chegar-se na 2FN, 3FN ou qualquer outra forma normal mais além.

Comment: E isso tudo apenas na 1FN? Sem precisar se preocupar com a 3FN?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Sim.

Comment: Bem que eu suspeitava que a pergunta estava fazendo uma confusão ao falar da 3FN... mas primeiro eu questiono as minhas verdades, então eu fiquei confuso. Obrigado por esclarecer

Comment: Agradeço por tirar minha dúvida, de fato eu não havia prestado atenção  que quando ocorre a composição ou agregação entra as tabelas, a relação M:N deixa de existir e passa a ser 2, eu pensava que ela continuava existindo junto.