# Exemplo de Esquema respeitando a 3FN?

Tags: banco-de-dados, modelagem, arquitetura-de-software, tabela-banco-de-dados, normalização

Ao estudar sobre 3FN deparei-me com 2 exemplos interessantes e fiquei me perguntando se ao realizar uma pequena alteração, os exemplos continuariam atendendo a 3FN.

Explicação sobre o [conceito de 3FN](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/251916/por-que-esquemas-normalizados-at%C3%A9-3fn-n%C3%A3o-possuem-relacionamentos-nn)

## Explicando o Contexto

Abaixo vai uma ilustração apresentada pelo livro para exemplificar a normalização de um esquema que atenda a 3FN.
Observe o exemplo abaixo e compare com a mudança.

### Exemplo do livro

[image: exemplo de 3FN]

Observe que do jeito que está ilustrado, um funcionário somente pode trabalhar em um departamento e não em vários, e cada departamento pode ser composto por vários funcionários.

### Meu Exemplo

Gostaria de saber se caso o atributo `Dnumero` na tabela `DF1` fosse chave primária, **o esquema continuaria respeitando a 3FN?**

> **Regra de negócio**: `Um funcionário pode trabalhar em mais de um departamento e em cada departamento existe mais de um funcionário.`
>
> > Ocorre que essa pequena alteração da chave `Dnumero` é necessária porque um funcionário pode trabalhar em vários departamentos, e cada departamento pode ser composto por vários funcionários.

Repare que um dos funcionários pode ser o gerente do departamento, cada departamento tem um gerente que também é um funcionário.

### Observações finais

Como fazer para o exemplo respeitar a 3FN e a regra de negócio ao mesmo tempo?

Comment: Acho que não é interessante dividir uma  pergunta em duas partes, e se puder, coloque o esquema de como ficou com sua modificação

Comment: O esquema é igual ao do livro, a única diferença é a que Dnumero vira chave primaria junto com CPF na tabela DF1, não faz sentido fazer outro desenho do mesmo esquema só com essa alteração mínima, mas como você pediu eu vou fazer.

Comment: Acho que entendi, não precisa fazer desenho,  se estivesse usando algum software pra modelar, era só colocar o print mas se vai te dar trabalho, deixa

Comment: Aos usuários que marcaram a pergunta como pendente, alguém poderia me orientar de alguma forma, para que a pergunta seja retirada do status de [PENDENTE] a pergunta foi bem votada, eu ja fiz várias edições e continua com esse status